# How to display tab bar icon in react navigation 4

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to display bottom tab tar in react-navigation 4, but there is no luck to make it happen, even I use it. Can anyone help me to find the problem with my code or which option should I use?

```
static navigationOptions = {
    title: "Map",
    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => {
      return <Icon name="home" size={30} color={tintColor} />;
    }
}
```

in any component screen, it does still not work.

**Here is my router**

I want to apply the bottom tab icon to homescreen

```
const MainAuthenticated = createAppContainer(
  createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
      main: {
        screen: createBottomTabNavigator({
          Marketplace: {
            screen: createStackNavigator({
              home: {
                screen: HomeScreen,
              },
              profile: { screen: Profile },
              business: { screen: MyBusiness },

              logout: { screen: Logout },

              itemlist: { screen: ItemList },
              itemcreate: { screen: ItemCreate },
              itemdetail: { screen: ItemDetail },
              businesscreate: { screen: BusinessCreate },
              businessdetail: { screen: MyBusinessDetail },
            }),
          },
          XOrders: { screen: OrderScreen },
          Favorite: { screen: FavoriteScreen },
        }),
      },
    },
    {
      defaultNavigationOptions: {
        tabBarVisible: false,
      },
    },
  ),
);
```

Comment: why are use adding with static navigationOptions ? Are you updating the icon in the component?

Comment: I just tried different way to make trying to make it work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the working code to add the bottom tab bar icon in `react-navigation v4`

```
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';

export default createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Settings: SettingsScreen,
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        let IconComponent = Ionicons;
        let iconName;
        if (routeName === 'Home') {
          iconName = focused
            ? 'ios-information-circle'
            : 'ios-information-circle-outline';
          // Sometimes we want to add badges to some icons.
          // You can check the implementation below.
          IconComponent = HomeIconWithBadge;
        } else if (routeName === 'Settings') {
          iconName = focused ? 'ios-list-box' : 'ios-list';
        }

        // You can return any component that you like here!
        return <IconComponent name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
      },
    }),
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: 'tomato',
      inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
    },
  }
);
```

If you wanted to use some `.png` or `jpeg` or some other image file instead of vector icons just replace this

```
<IconComponent name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} /> // replace this with below

<Image source={require('your image path')} style={{height: 30, width: 30}} />
```

Comment: The code cannot blend in, many curly bracket mistakes

Comment: Where you want me to apply this code specifically from my above code ? is it in router.js file I'm showing or in any individual component screen file?

Comment: Brackets mistakes fixed and you can try to replace this bottom tab component with your tab component and icons will work then you can see and add your icons in the bottom tab as above described way.

Comment: It's worked, thank you so much for your time and help Mr.Waheed Akhtar. However HomeIconWIthBadge seem it doesn't work.

Comment: there could be some problem with the icon name you can try different icons from here.
https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/

Comment: I 've try to use HOME icon Mr. Waheed Akhtar, and it already worked, and I just comment out the code of HomeIconWIthBadge, because I haven't figure out how to do it yet. Anyway thank again for your help. I am really appreciated.

Comment: No problem, happy to help.

Comment: Excuse me Mr. @Waheed_Akhtar can you tell me how can I use my own custom image instead of using Ionicon icon with your above code solution?

Comment: @PhokChanrithisak I have edited my answer to your question.